# Getting the servers time while on the clients machine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that gets an encoded json array from php, the script calculates the current time, the time something started and the duration. What this does is start a countdown until the duration reaches zero... Then the ajax makes a call to get the new json array from php and new information is displayed to the user.

While my script functions correctly on the server, if the user is in a different timezone or just has their clock set incorectly the countdown timer will never reach zero when it needs to.. Therefore the users display will not update accordingly.

So within my script i have a variable called "now" ... this is the current time on the machine that has accessed the webpage. What i need to do is sucessfully get the servers time and input that into the "now" variable....

The "now" variable must also be updated when my timer reaches zero so that the calculations are sucessfull.

I have coded a very small PHP file that encodes the servers time in milliseconds.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$serverTime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
echo json_encode($serverTime);
?>
```

How can i add another ajax call to the script below so that the "now" variable is updated with the servers time.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { "cache-control" : "no-cache" }
});

var PlayList = function (onUpdate, onError)
{
    // store user callbacks
    this.onUpdate = onUpdate; 
    this.onError  = onError;

    // setup internal event handlers
    this.onSongEnd = onSongEnd.bind (this);

    // allocate an Ajax handler
    try
    {
        this.ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest
            ? new XMLHttpRequest()
            : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // fatal error: could not get an Ajax handler
        this.onError ("could not allocated Ajax handler");
    }
    this.ajax.onreadystatechange = onAjaxUpdate.bind(this);

    // launch initial request
    this.onSongEnd ();

    // ------------------------------------------
    // interface
    // ------------------------------------------

    // try another refresh in the specified amount of seconds
    this.retry = function (delay)
    {
        setTimeout (this.onSongEnd, delay*5000);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------
    // ancillary functions
    // ------------------------------------------

    // called when it's time to refresh the playlist
    function onSongEnd ()
    {
        // ask for a playlist update
        this.ajax.open('GET', 'playlist.php', // <-- reference your PHP script here
                       true);
        this.ajax.send(null);       
    }

    // called to handle Ajax request progress
    function onAjaxUpdate ()
    {       
        if (this.ajax.readyState != 4) return;
        if (this.ajax.status == 200)
        {
            // get response
            var list = eval ('('+this.ajax.responseText+')');

            // compute milliseconds remaining till the end of the current song
            var start = new Date(list[0].date_played.replace(' ', 'T')).getTime();
```

The next line of code gets the current time on the clients machine, i need this variable to utilize the php script so that now = the millisecond result from php

```
var now   = new Date (                                    ).getTime();
```

continued...

```
var d = start - now + 6500
                  + parseInt(list[0].duration);
            if (d < 0)

            {
                // no new song started, retry in 3 seconds
                d = 3000;
            }
            else
            {
                // notify caller
                this.onUpdate (list);
            }

            // schedule next refresh
            setTimeout (this.onSongEnd, d);

        }
        else
        {
            // Ajax request failed. Most likely a fatal error
            this.onError ("Ajax request failed");
        }       
    }
}

var list = new PlayList (playlistupdate, playlisterror);

function playlistupdate (list)
{
for (var i = 0 ; i != list.length ; i++)
    {
        var song = list[i];

    }
{

    document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
    document.getElementById("list0title").innerHTML=list[0].title;
    document.getElementById("list0label").innerHTML=list[0].label;
    document.getElementById("list0albumyear").innerHTML=list[0].albumyear;
    document.getElementById("list0picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '" width="170" height="170"/>';

    document.getElementById("list1artist").innerHTML=list[1].artist;
    document.getElementById("list1title").innerHTML=list[1].title;
    document.getElementById("list1label").innerHTML=list[1].label;
    document.getElementById("list1albumyear").innerHTML=list[1].albumyear;
    document.getElementById("list1picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[1].picture + '" width="84" height="84"/>';

    document.getElementById("list2artist").innerHTML=list[2].artist;
    document.getElementById("list2title").innerHTML=list[2].title;
    document.getElementById("list2label").innerHTML=list[2].label;
    document.getElementById("list2albumyear").innerHTML=list[2].albumyear;
    document.getElementById("list2picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[2].picture + '" width="84" height="84"/>';

    document.getElementById("list3artist").innerHTML=list[3].artist;
    document.getElementById("list3title").innerHTML=list[3].title;
    document.getElementById("list3label").innerHTML=list[3].label;
    document.getElementById("list3albumyear").innerHTML=list[3].albumyear;
    document.getElementById("list3picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[3].picture + '" width="84" height="84"/>';

    document.getElementById("list4artist").innerHTML=list[4].artist;
    document.getElementById("list4title").innerHTML=list[4].title;
    document.getElementById("list4label").innerHTML=list[4].label;
    document.getElementById("list4albumyear").innerHTML=list[4].albumyear;
    document.getElementById("list4picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[4].picture + '" width="84" height="84"/>';

$('.nowPlayNoAnimate').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('nowPlayAnimate', $(this).parent().width() < $(this).width());
});

}
}

function playlisterror (msg)
{
    // display error message
    console.log ("Ajax error: "+msg);

    //retry
    list.retry (10); // retry in 10 seconds
}
```

Many Thanks for reading through! i hope i have explained myself correctly...

Comment: The first line of your first snippet makes a call to jQuery's `ajaxSetup` method. Why are you then making your own XHR request?

Comment: Using new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)) you can create a Date-object from a specific UTC time.

Comment: @mike w I was using this so that nothing is ever cache'd on the clients machine... thanks..

Comment: I have a very broken knowledge of this language, apologies

Comment: if you want to solve the time zone problem between server-client, send time from server in gmt format then format it for client's time zone.